Script to update samba dns not working when executed from isc-dhcp server (while works fine when I become the exact same user)
I am going nuts here. Running ubuntu 24.0, which is hosting my samba active directory server, and isc-dhcp server.
I can call samba-tool to add DNS records from any user on my server.
$ samba-tool dns add 192.168.2.100 SPATIEBAS.LAN Chromecast A 192.168.2.6 -U Administrator@SPATIEBAS.LAN --password ******
Record added successfully

I can even become dhcpd user, and add / remove DNS entries
$ sudo -u dhcpd /bin/bash
$ samba-tool dns add 127.0.0.1 SPATIEBAS.LAN desktop-ubuntu A 192.168.2.208 -U Administrator@SPATIEBAS.LAN --password ******
Record added successfully

But when I call this EXACT SAME command, from a script which is executed by isc-dhcp (as the dhcpd user, I triple checked, I am sure the user running isc-dhcp is dhcpd)
2024-09-22T14:56:00.822329+02:00 server sh[11401]: /usr/bin/samba-tool dns add 192.168.2.100 SPATIEBAS.LAN Chromecast A 192.168.2.6 -U Administrator@SPATIEBAS.LAN --password ******
2024-09-22T14:56:00.822342+02:00 server sh[11401]: 2024-09-22T14:56:00.871658+02:00 server sh[11425]: WARNING: Using passwords on command line is insecure. Installing the setproctitle python module will hide these from shortly after program start.
2024-09-22T14:56:00.876715+02:00 server sh[11425]: Password for [ Administrator@SPATIEBAS.LAN --password D*****]:Password for [ Administrator@SPATIEBAS.LAN --password *****]:Failed to bind to uuid 50abc2a4-574d-40b3-9d66-ee4fd5fba076 for ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.2.100[49153,sign,abstract_syntax=50abc2a4-574d-40b3-9d66-ee4fd5fba076/0x00000005,localaddress=192.168.2.100] NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
2024-09-22T14:56:00.876764+02:00 server sh[11425]: ERROR: Connecting to DNS RPC server 192.168.2.100 failed with (3221225581, 'The attempted logon is invalid. This is either due to a bad username or authentication information.')


I disable app armor completely for testing purposes.
I opened 49153 in ufw (for no reason, because both processes run on the same computer)
I became user dhcpd only to find out that it works perfectly when executing it from command line

Am I missing the obvious here??
UPDATE
Reverted back a little removing the hacks where I put the password hardcoded in the script for testing purposes. So now I am using samba's script "as-is".
I can run it successfully like this
sudo -u dhcpd /bin/dhcp-dyndns.sh delete 192.168.2.123 123 piet
Record deleted successfully

add / delete both work. It's irrelevant what the script does, the only important thing is; it executes.
But, when I call the exact same thing from the isc-dhcp-server context (which is executed by user dhcpd then it errors out
2024-09-22T23:14:00.028725+02:00 server dhcpd[3061]: DHCPACK on 192.168.2.245 to 54:44:a3:ff:a8:49 (Samsung) via enp5s0
2024-09-22T23:14:02.080414+02:00 server dhcpd[3061]: Commit: IP: 192.168.2.203 DHCID: bc:c7:46:a7:76:e7 Name: desktop-ubuntu
2024-09-22T23:14:02.080549+02:00 server dhcpd[3061]: execute_statement argv[0] = /bin/dhcp-dyndns.sh
2024-09-22T23:14:02.080577+02:00 server dhcpd[3061]: execute_statement argv[1] = add
2024-09-22T23:14:02.080606+02:00 server dhcpd[3061]: execute_statement argv[2] = 192.168.2.203
2024-09-22T23:14:02.080635+02:00 server dhcpd[3061]: execute_statement argv[3] = bc:c7:46:a7:76:e7
2024-09-22T23:14:02.080661+02:00 server dhcpd[3061]: execute_statement argv[4] = desktop-ubuntu
2024-09-22T23:14:02.080723+02:00 server dhcpd[3109]: Unable to execute /bin/dhcp-dyndns.sh: Permission denied
2024-09-22T23:14:02.080758+02:00 server dhcpd[3061]: execute: /bin/dhcp-dyndns.sh exit status 32512

Again:

app armor is disabled
/bin/dhcp-dyndns.sh is owned by dhcpd:dhcdp
/bin/dhcp-dyndns.sh has rwx permissions

localadmin@server:~$ ls -al /bin/dhcp-dyndns.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dhcpd dhcpd 12286 Sep 22 23:01 /bin/dhcp-dyndns.sh

I am totally lost....

What is the password? Does it contain any special characters (*?+| etc.)? How are you passing it in the script? Is it hard-coded? Do you have it in a variable? Does it work if you quote the password? Can you show us the full script? As an aside, to get a shell as a different user, you can just do sudo -iu dhcpd, no need to explicitly call /bin/bash unless the dhcpd user has no default shell set up.

Hi @terdon, thanks for the comments, reverted back a bit to get rid of some of the hacks. Still hitting a brick wall here.... So frustrating

Hi @terdon, problem solved. It WAS in app armor. I am not sure what exactly happens when I sudo systemctl stop apparmor, but or I rebooted and missed that, or something reactivated it, but after a while I started noticing the app armor errors in my syslog. I had to add quite a bunch of exclusions for the script, but also for the samba tool to operate.... Anyway.... it works! YEY!
